# How do I style a class in a div that has a parenthesis in it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement flags from a image file, its fetched by curl so i cannot change the class. The class has a parenthesis in it, and as parenthesis are invalid operators(?) in css im unable to style it. Does anyone know how i can be able to add style to it?
[image: Image with parenthesis that i want to style]

Comment: ..and specifically - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6592488/2802040

Comment: http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dpdoNV

Comment: Sorry guys. I didnt see this great tool by mathiasbynens in how to escape characters in css via the links above. Thank you!